# Why does `OpCode.Value` have the "wrong" endianness?

Tags: .net, endianness, cil, reflection.emit, opcode

**Facts:**

1. The correct encoding for the CIL instruction [`rethrow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.rethrow.aspx)'s op-code is the two-byte sequence `FE 1A`.
2. [`OpCodes.Rethrow.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcode.value.aspx) (which has type `short`) has value `0xFE1A` on my little-endian machine.
3. [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) honours the machine's endianness when converting to/from byte sequences.
4. On my little-endian machine, `BitConverter.GetBytes(OpCodes.Rethrow.Value)` results in the byte sequence `1A FE`.

That means, serializing an `OpCode.Value` on a little-endian machine using `BitConverter` does not produce the correct encoding for the op-code; the byte order is reversed.

**Questions:**

- Is the byte ordering of [`OpCode.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcode.value.aspx) documented (and if so, where?), or is it an "implementation detail"?
- Does step 4 above on a big-endian machine also result in the wrong byte ordering? That is, would `OpCodes.Rethrow.Value` be `0x1AFE` on a big-endian machine?

Comment: You cant combine the opcode like that. The metadata reader will nibble the content and upon finding `FE` will know it is a long version. If it represented the other way around, well then you would have a hard time reading it.

Comment: @leppie: I know that `FE` has to appear first in the instruction byte stream. My question is about the byte order of the op-code encodings as stored in `OpCode.Value`.

Comment: Probably for easier reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reached the conclusion that serializing an op-code representation based on the `OpCode.Value` property, i.e.:

```
OpCode someOpCode = …;
byte[] someOpCodeEncoding = BitConverter.GetBytes(someOpCode.Value);
```

is a bad idea, but not because of the use of [`BitConverter.GetBytes(short)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk3sts66.aspx) , whose behaviour is well-documented. The main culprit is the `OpCode.Value` property, [whose documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcode.value.aspx) is vague in two respects:

1. It states that this property contains "the value of the immediate operand", which may or may not refer to the op-code's encoding; that term doesn't appear anywhere in the CLI specification.
2. Even when we assume that it *does* in fact contain an op-code's encoding, the documentation says nothing about byte order. (Byte order comes into play when converting between `byte[]` and `short`.)

Why am I basing my argument on MSDN documentation, and not on the CLI standard? Because `System.Reflection.Emit` is not part of the Reflection Library as defined by the CLI standard. For this reason, I think it's fairly safe to say that [the MSDN reference documentation for this namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.aspx) is as close as it gets to an official specification. (But unlike @Hans Passant's answer, I would not take one step further and claim that the reference source is in any way a specification.)

**Conclusion:**

There are two ways to output the op-code encoding for a given `OpCode` object:

- Stay with `System.Reflection.Emit` functionality and use `ILGenerator.Emit(someOpCode)`. This may be too restrictive in some situations.
- Create your own mapping between op-code encodings (i.e. `byte[]` sequences) and the various `OpCode` objects.

Comment: Alternative: don't use `OpCode` objects if you're not using reflection? If you just like using `OpCodes.Rethrow.Value` for readability, you can achieve the same by using [Mono Cecil's `OpCodes`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/OpCodes.cs) class; its [`OpCode`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/OpCode.cs) struct has explicit `Op1` and `Op2` properties.

Answer (score 3):

The Value property looks like this in the Reference Source:

```
public short Value
{
    get
    {
        if (m_size == 2)
            return (short) (m_s1 << 8 | m_s2);
        return (short) m_s2;
    }
}
```

That looks entirely sane of course, m_s2 is always the Least Significant Byte.  Looking at ILGenerator:

```
    internal void InternalEmit(OpCode opcode)
    {
        if (opcode.m_size == 1)
        {
            m_ILStream[m_length++] = opcode.m_s2;
        }
        else
        {
            m_ILStream[m_length++] = opcode.m_s1;
            m_ILStream[m_length++] = opcode.m_s2;
        }

        UpdateStackSize(opcode, opcode.StackChange());

    }
```

Which is want you expected, the 0xfe byte gets emitted first.

So the framework code carefully avoids taking a dependency on endian-ness.  CIL doesn't have an endian-ness dependency, no variable length data ever does.  True for text files, utf-8 encoding, x86 core machine code instructions.  An CIL.  So if you convert variable length data to a *single* value, like the Value property getter does, then that code inevitable *does* make a conversion from non-endian-ness data to endian-ness data.  Which inevitably gets half of the world upset because they think it was the wrong way around.  And 100% of all programmers that run into it.

Probably the best way is to do it like the framework does and recover m_s1 and m_s2 as quickly as you can, using your own version of the Opcode type.  Easy to do with:

```
foo.m_s1 = opc.Value >> 8;
foo.m_s2 = opc.Value & 0xff;
foo.m_size = opc.Size;
```

Which has no endian-ness dependency.

Comment: _"it doesn't do what InternalEmit() does"_: Are you saying then that the byte order in `OpCode.Value` is an (internal) implementation detail? Or does the [.NET reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) actually have the character of a public specification?

Comment: The Opcode.Value property is not an internal implementation detail.  It is just a public property that *you* can use, the implementation doesn't use it.

Comment: Please re-read my question: I am not asking about `OpCode.Value` itself, but about *its byte order*.

Comment: _"which has no endian-ness dependency_": You're proving yourself wrong with the code that performs bit operations. You're basing this on your knowledge of the reference source, which IMHO cannot replace a public specification or documentation. Even so: With statements such as, _"do it like the framework does"_, you've actually helped me draw my own conclusions, namely that we're talking about something which is in fact undocumented.

Comment: Side note: There's one minor inaccuracy in your answer: Unlike the op-code, there *is* other data in a CIL instruction byte stream that has a certain endianness (always little-endian AFAIK): e.g. embedded metadata tokens, or relative offsets denoting branch targets.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var yourStream = MemoryStream();
var writer = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(yourStream);
writer.Write(OpCodes.Rethrow.Value);
```

You don't need to worry about byte order since the BinaryWriter (or reader) will handle the implementation details for you. I suspect that the reason why you're getting the "wrong" byte order is that you're applying the BitConverter on the OpCode value when it's already decoded as little endian, and applying the BitConverter.GetShort() call again will reverse the byte order, giving you the "wrong" result.

Comment: You won't know unless you try the implementation. I practically work with this stuff every day since I'm currently rewriting System.Reflection.* from scratch--so yes, I know. :)

Comment: Please don't misunderstand me: I trust that you know your stuff, and I believe that your code might just work fine. But I was asking for documentation (if it exists) because I would prefer if my code (which is an library that extends `System.Reflection` btw.) wasn't actually relying on undocumented behaviour of one implementation of the CLI standard.

Comment: I've just tried out your code. Unfortunately, it doesn't do the right thing. The [documentation for `BinaryReader.Write(short)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/091b1s67.aspx) says: _"BinaryWriter stores this data type in little endian format."_. I've tried it out, and indeed, you end up with `1A` written to the stream before `FE`.